# Border шире элемента

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, не могу понять почему border шире самого элемента

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #2F3136;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header1 {
  padding: 1px 0px 0px 4px;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  color: #A6A7A8;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #202225;
  border: 2px solid #202225;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  background: #202225;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid #202225;
  width: 1300px;
  height: 800px;
  position: absolute;
}

.contentimage {
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
}

.paspartu {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

.leftside {
  color: white;
  background: #202225;
  border: 2px solid #202225;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 27px;
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}

ul li {
  background: #090214;
  border-top: 7px solid #090214;
  border-left: 7px solid #090214;
  border-right: 7px solid #090214;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #090214;
  border-top: 7px solid #090214;
  border-left: 7px solid #090214;
  border-right: 7px solid #090214;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class='header1'>Discord</div>

<div class='leftside'>
  <ul>
    <div class='rounded'>
      <li><img width=1 00% src='pro.jpg'></li>
      <li><img width=1 00% src='pro.jpg'></li>
      <li><img width=1 00% src='pro.jpg'></li>
      <li><img width=1 00% src='pro.jpg'></li>
      <li><img width=1 00% src='pro.jpg'></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class='content'>
  <div class='contentimage'>
    <div class='paspartu'>
      <img width=50% src='text.jpg'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто div с классом paspartu в силу того, что является блочным элементом растягивается на всю предоставленную ему ширину, то есть на ширину родительского контейнера, равного 1000 пиксилей

Comment: Вам либо изображению рамку задать надо, либо поменять свойство display у элемента .paspartu

Answer (score 1):

> Блочным называется элемент, который отображается на веб-странице в виде прямоугольника.
>   Такой элемент занимает всю доступную ширину, высота элемента определяется его содержимым, и он всегда начинается с новой строки.
>   К блочным элементам относятся контейнеры `<div>`, `<h1>`, `<p>` и др.

[Блочные элементы | htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/content/blochnye-elementy)

---

Если вы хотите сделать бордюр именно у изображение, то можете задать бордюр непосредственно к изображению:

```
img {
  border: 2px solid gray;
}
```

---

> Дело в том, что если использовать img, бордер применится и к иконкам

Вы можете использовать следующее:

Определить конкретный класс для картинок с бордюром.

```
<img class="border" src="">

img.border {...}
```

Класс для иконок и "запретить" использовать свойство этому классу.

```
<img class="icon" src="">

img:not(.icon) {...}
```

Или, если все иконки имеют совпадение в адресе, допустим "уникальный путь", типо `/img/icon/...`, то можно сделать ещё и так.

```
img:not([src^="/img/icon/") {...}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что если использовать img, бордер применится и к иконкам

Comment: @ГенаПевко, дополнил